# DateValue Returning British Units

Tags: excel, date, vba

I download a spreadsheet daily that has columns of dates formatted as mm/dd/yyyy that my Excel does not recognize as dates. I need to convert them to usable dates via a macro.

I found a very useful post here that I tweaked and came up with the following:

```
    'DateValue Cells
Dim v As Long, vCOLs As Variant
vCOLs = Array("E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "L", "M", "Q", "R")
With ActiveSheet
    For v = LBound(vCOLs) To UBound(vCOLs)
        If CBool(Application.CountA(.Columns(vCOLs(v)))) Then _
            .Columns(vCOLs(v)).TextToColumns Destination:=.Columns(vCOLs(v)), _
              DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 4)
    Next v
End With
```

The result is flipping the date into dd/mm/yyyy leaving my data incorrect and unusable.  I read that I could do a text-to-columns, break it up, and put it back together, but with 9 columns of dates already that seems to be too many steps.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Text to column Step 3 Window Select Date Option button and select your desired Date formatting from the drop down.